# React Js ErrorBoundary only working for the main layout components and not for nested components

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

I am using errorboundaries in my code and when I use it in the file where I am rendering my main layout components it works, Eg.:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
<header></header>
</ErrorBoundary>
<ErrorBoundary>
<main/> //this component has an error
</ErrorBoundary>
<ErrorBoundary>
<footer></footer>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The above code works and the fallback UI is shown for the error that is in the `main` component. But when I use errorboundary component inside the main component file it does not work,
Eg of errorboundary that does not work:

```
class main extends React.Component {
//code
<ErrorBoundary>
{object}
</ErrorBoundary>
//more code
```

This does not work and the whole app crashes instead, displaying only a blank page. Why might this be happening and how to deal with it? Thank you.

Comment: according to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#where-to-place-error-boundaries), wrapping your root component in `ErrorBoundry` should do the job. And also please note that [Error boundaries do not catch errors for](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) some errors.

Comment: @saeedghotb Thank you for your answer, the whole app is at least not crashing anymore. But the problem still remains and instead of only removing the part where the `{object}` is and displaying the fallback UI it is still replacing the whole component `main` with the fallback UI.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is possible or is in face a good idea, but in development mode the error screen will pop to notify the developers of the problem. maybe pressing the escape button after reading the crash message will help.

Comment: @saeedghotb yes the errorboundary is working now, but the issue is that it replaces the whole `main` component with the fallback UI instead of only the section of the screen where `{object}` is rendered

Comment: @saeedghotb I figured it out. Errorboundary catches the error in components. So it wasn't working earlier, but when I rendered a faulty component in between the errorboundary `<ErrorComponent/>` it worked. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Errorboundary catches the error in components. So it wasn't working earlier, but when I rendered a faulty component in between the ErrorBoundary instead, it worked.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
<FaultyComponent/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

it worked.